# Redirect to a specific activity upon push notification is clicked on android studio

Tags: android, redirect, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

I'm struggling on a Android app to redirect the app to a specific activity page whenever all the incoming push notification is clicked. I am new to android development and sorry for my programming.

Below are are android manifest.xml for push notification part. appreciated if there are any comment on this topic:-

```
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.younginnovators.sjk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<!-- VERY IMPORTANT! Don't forget this permission, or in-app billing won't work. -->

<uses-permission android:name="com.younginnovators.sjk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Push Notifications Receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".backgroundservices.PushNotificationBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.younginnovators.sjk" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- /Push Notifications Receiver -->


    <!-- Push Notifications Service -->
    <service android:name=".backgroundservices.PushnotificationService" />
    <!-- /Push Notifications Service -->
```

Comment: "GCM" is obsolete. Upgrade to Firebase. Docs are simpler to understand... By the way, you didn't say what the actual problem is.

Comment: Hi muratgu , my problem is my app currently go to homepage after clicked push notification , wonder if i can redirect to a specific page whenever push notification is clicked

Comment: Thanks for advice , i have never try firebase , will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Try those codes in preferred activity class. 
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html for more information on notification