# How to open links in the corresponding page in webview android application and not in browser

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-manifest

I was tired of searching and trying months ago to try opening links in my webview app but not the browser. I hope I find a solution here.

if I add any links in my notifications, it only opens the application homepage.
I use onesignal to send push notification

This is my app class:

```
package com.drbrandat.grinta;

public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "4cda77cb-1587-4b27-b708-7a427b9c1b1b";

private String push_url = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    //OneSignal Push
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
    OneSignal.setAppId(String.valueOf(R.string.ONESIGNAL_APP_ID));
    OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationHandler());
}



private class NotificationHandler implements OneSignal.OSNotificationOpenedHandler {

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
        try {
            JSONObject data = result.getNotification().getAdditionalData();

            String webViewUrl = (data != null) ? data.optString("url", null) : null;
            String browserUrl = result.getNotification().getLaunchURL();

            if (webViewUrl != null || browserUrl != null) {
                if (browserUrl != null) {
                    browserUrl = (browserUrl == null) ? webViewUrl : browserUrl;
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(browserUrl));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    Log.v("INFO", "Received notification while app was on foreground or url for browser");
                } else {
                    push_url = webViewUrl;
                }
            } else {
                Intent mainIntent;
                mainIntent = new Intent(App.this, MainActivity.class);
                mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public synchronized String getPushUrl(){
    String url = push_url;
    push_url = null;
    return url;
}

public synchronized void setPushUrl(String url){
    this.push_url = url;
}
}
```

This is my main activity:

```
package com.drbrandat.grinta.activity;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.drbrandat.grinta.App;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.Config;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.R;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.adapter.NavigationAdapter;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.drawer.menu.Action;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.drawer.menu.MenuItemCallback;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.drawer.menu.SimpleMenu;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.fragment.WebFragment;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.util.ThemeUtils;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.widget.SwipeableViewPager;
import com.drbrandat.grinta.widget.webview.WebToAppWebClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import com.tjeannin.apprate.AppRate;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MenuItemCallback{

//Views
public Toolbar mToolbar;
public View mHeaderView;
public TabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
public SwipeableViewPager mViewPager;
//App Navigation Structure
private NavigationAdapter mAdapter;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private SimpleMenu menu;

private WebFragment CurrentAnimatingFragment = null;
private int CurrentAnimation = 0;

//Identify toolbar state
private static int NO = 0;
private static int HIDING = 1;
private static int SHOWING = 2;

//Keep track of the interstitials we show
private int interstitialCount = -1;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
// OneSignal
private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "4cda77cb-1587-4b27-b708-7a427b9c1b1b";

ImageView previous;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
    OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    try {
        WebFragment.notification_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Notification_url","");
    }catch (Exception e){
        WebFragment.notification_url = "";
    }
    ThemeUtils.setTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mHeaderView = (View) findViewById(R.id.header_container);
    mSlidingTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager = (SwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    previous = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previous);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    mAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        String data = intent.getDataString();
        ((App) getApplication()).setPushUrl(data);

    }

    //Hiding ActionBar/Toolbar
    if (Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR)
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    if (getHideTabs())
        mSlidingTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    hasPermissionToDo(this, Config.PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mViewPager.getLayoutParams();
    if ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && getHideTabs()) || ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR || getHideTabs()) && getCollapsingActionBar())){
        lp.topMargin = 0;
    } else if ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR || getHideTabs()) || (!Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && !getHideTabs() && getCollapsingActionBar())){
        lp.topMargin = getActionBarHeight();
    } else if (!Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && !getHideTabs()){
        lp.topMargin = getActionBarHeight() * 2;
    }

    mViewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);

    //Tabs
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);

    mSlidingTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mSlidingTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (getCollapsingActionBar()) {
                showToolbar(getFragment());
            }
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            showInterstitial();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSlidingTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        if (Config.ICONS.length > i  && Config.ICONS[i] != 0) {
            mSlidingTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(Config.ICONS[i]);
        }
    }

    //Drawer
    if (Config.USE_DRAWER) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        DrawerLayout drawer =  ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, mToolbar, 0, 0);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //Menu items
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        menu = new SimpleMenu(navigationView.getMenu(), this);
        configureMenu(menu);

        if (Config.HIDE_DRAWER_HEADER) {
            navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            navigationView.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
        } else {
            if (Config.DRAWER_ICON != R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                ((ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon)).setImageResource(Config.DRAWER_ICON);
            else {
                ((ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.launcher_icon)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    } else {
        ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    //Admob
    if (!getResources().getString(R.string.ad_banner_id).equals("")) {
        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    } else {
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id).length() > 0 && Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL > 0){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id));
        AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
            }

        });
    }

    //Application rating
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.rate_title))
            .setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.rate_message), getString(R.string.app_name)))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.rate_yes), null)
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.rate_never), null)
            .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.rate_later), null);

    new AppRate(this)
            .setShowIfAppHasCrashed(false)
            .setMinDaysUntilPrompt(2)
            .setMinLaunchesUntilPrompt(2)
            .setCustomDialog(builder)
            .init();

    //Showing the splash screen
    if (Config.SPLASH) {
        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.mmprogressbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //getFragment().browser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //Toolbar styling
    if (Config.TOOLBAR_ICON != 0) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(Config.TOOLBAR_ICON);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (!Config.USE_DRAWER){
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
        }
    }



    previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WebView browser = getFragment().browser;
            browser.goBack();
        }
    });

}

// using the back button of the device
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    View customView = null;
    WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback = null;
    if (getFragment().chromeClient != null) {
        customView = getFragment().chromeClient.getCustomView();
        customViewCallback = getFragment().chromeClient.getCustomViewCallback();
    }

    if ((customView == null)
            && getFragment().browser.canGoBack()) {
        getFragment().browser.goBack();
    } else if (customView != null
            && customViewCallback != null) {
        customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    if(isHome){
        previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    }else{
        previous.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }


    //Adjust menu item visibility/availability based on settings
    if (Config.HIDE_MENU_SHARE) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.share).setVisible(false);
    }
    if (Config.HIDE_MENU_HOME) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.home).setVisible(false);
    }
    if (Config.HIDE_MENU_NAVIGATION){
        menu.findItem(R.id.previous).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.next).setVisible(false);
    }
    if (!Config.SHOW_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        menu.findItem(R.id.notification_settings).setVisible(false);
    }

    ThemeUtils.tintAllIcons(menu, this);

    return true;
}

//added
public static boolean isHome =  true;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    WebView browser = getFragment().browser;
    if (item.getItemId() == (R.id.next)) {

        browser.goForward();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.previous) {

        browser.goBack();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share) {

        getFragment().shareURL();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {

        AboutDialog();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {

        browser.loadUrl(getFragment().mainUrl);
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.close) {
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getText(R.string.exit_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.notification_settings){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

/**
 * Showing the About Dialog
 */
private void AboutDialog() {
    // setting the dialogs text, and making the links clickable
    final TextView message = new TextView(this);
    // i.e.: R.string.dialog_message =>
    final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(
            this.getText(R.string.dialog_about));
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    message.setTextSize(15f);
    int padding  = Math.round(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    message.setPadding(padding, 15, padding, 15);
    message.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.dialog_about)));
    message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    // creating the actual dialog

    AlertDialog.Builder AlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about)))
            // .setTitle(R.string.about)
            .setCancelable(true)
            // .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", null).setView(message).create().show();
}

/**
 * Set the ActionBar Title
 * @param title title
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getCount() == 1 && !Config.USE_DRAWER && !Config.STATIC_TOOLBAR_TITLE)
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

/**
 * @return the Current WebFragment
 */
public WebFragment getFragment(){
    return (WebFragment) mAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
}

/**
 * Hide the Splash Screen
 */
public void hideSplash() {

    if (Config.SPLASH) {
        if (findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // hide splash image
                    findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(
                            View.GONE);
                }
                // set a delay before splashscreen is hidden
            }, Config.SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
        }

        if (findViewById(R.id.mmprogressbar).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // hide splash image
                    findViewById(R.id.mmprogressbar).setVisibility(
                            View.GONE);
                }
                // set a delay before splashscreen is hidden
            }, Config.SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Hide the toolbar
 */
public void hideToolbar() {
    if (CurrentAnimation != HIDING) {
        CurrentAnimation = HIDING;
        AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();

        ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(getFragment().rl, "y", 0);
        ObjectAnimator animY1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeaderView, "y", -getActionBarHeight());
        animSetXY.playTogether(animY, animY1);

        animSetXY.start();
        animSetXY.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                CurrentAnimation = NO;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });

    }
}

/**
 * Show the toolbar
 * @param fragment for which to show the toolbar
 */
public void showToolbar(WebFragment fragment) {
    if (CurrentAnimation != SHOWING || fragment != CurrentAnimatingFragment) {

        CurrentAnimation = SHOWING;
        CurrentAnimatingFragment = fragment;
        AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fragment.rl, "y", getActionBarHeight());
        ObjectAnimator animY1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeaderView, "y", 0);
        animSetXY.playTogether(animY, animY1);

        animSetXY.start();
        animSetXY.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                CurrentAnimation = NO;
                CurrentAnimatingFragment = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });

    }
}

public int getActionBarHeight() {
    int mHeight = mToolbar.getHeight();

    //Just in case we get a unreliable result, get it from metrics
    if (mHeight == 0){
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        {
            mHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    return mHeight;
}

boolean getHideTabs(){
    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 1 || Config.USE_DRAWER){
        return true;
    } else {
        return Config.HIDE_TABS;
    }
}

public static boolean getCollapsingActionBar(){
    if (Config.COLLAPSING_ACTIONBAR && !Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Check permissions on app start
 * @param context
 * @param permissions Permissions to check
 * @return if the permissions are available
 */
private static boolean hasPermissionToDo(final Activity context, final String[] permissions) {
    boolean oneDenied = false;
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            oneDenied = true;
    }

    if (!oneDenied) return true;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.common_permission_explaination);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.common_permission_grant, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
            // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                context.requestPermissions(permissions,1);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    return false;
}

/**
 * Show an interstitial ad
 */
public void showInterstitial(){
    if (interstitialCount == (Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL - 1)) {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

        interstitialCount = 0;
    } else {
        interstitialCount++;
    }
}

/**
 * Configure the navigationView
 * @param menu to modify
 */
public void configureMenu(SimpleMenu menu){
    for (int i = 0; i < Config.TITLES.length; i++) {
        //The title
        String title = null;
        Object titleObj = Config.TITLES[i];
        if (titleObj instanceof Integer && !titleObj.equals(0)) {
            title = getResources().getString((int) titleObj);
        } else {
            title = (String) titleObj;
        }

        //The icon
        int icon = 0;
        if (Config.ICONS.length > i)
            icon = Config.ICONS[i];

        menu.add((String) Config.TITLES[i], icon, new Action(title, Config.URLS[i]));
    }

    menuItemClicked(menu.getFirstMenuItem().getValue(), menu.getFirstMenuItem().getKey());
}

@Override
public void menuItemClicked(Action action, MenuItem item) {


    if (WebToAppWebClient.urlShouldOpenExternally(action.url)){
        //Load url outside WebView
        try {
            startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(action.url)));
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            if (action.url.startsWith("intent://") || (action.url.startsWith("whatsapp:")
                    || (action.url.startsWith("tel:")))){
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(action.url.replace("intent://", "http://"))));
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(action.url.replace("whatsapp:", "http://")));
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(action.url.replace("tel:", "http://")));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_app_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Uncheck all other items, check the current item
        for (MenuItem menuItem : menu.getMenuItems())
            menuItem.setChecked(false);
        item.setChecked(true);

        //Close the drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        //Load the url
        if (getFragment() == null) return;
        getFragment().browser.loadUrl("about:blank");
        getFragment().setBaseUrl(action.url);

        //Show intersitial if applicable
        showInterstitial();
        Log.v("INFO", "Drawer Item Selected");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to use `Pending Intent` to redirect your notification from `activity` to `webView` or that layout where you added a widget of `webView`.

Comment: How can I do this in the code please @MDev

Comment: Any updates here

Comment: try this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/39070404/16765223

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. If you can edit the code I put here, I would be thankful.

Comment: have you got your notification link in your activity?

Comment: It only opens in main activity not in the URL that i put in the notification

Comment: but have you got an URL from Notification? means you completed the code to get an URL from a notification in your activity?

Comment: Yes I did that. It now opens but if the notification comes while the app in use it doesn't go anywhere.